# Does a Node js web server need a domain name to communicate with clients on other devices?

Tags: node.js, localhost, backend

I am working on a swift project for osx with Firebase. I have a node web server to communicate between the clients and the Firebase-server, but it's a localhost-server. Do I need a real domain name to make the server accessible to end-users on another device? (I don't want a web app, just the backend for myself)

Comment: No, you don't need to buy a domain name or use one you can just deploy it in some services or machine and grab the ip address then use it.

Answer (score 0):

you doesn't need a domain .. but you need a serve to deploy having ip address .. suggestion you can use cloud server

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

- make request on port that the nodejs uses, example http://101.01.01.01:8000
- use nginx like proxy, in this setup make your requests on 80 port (it's default), example http://101.01.01.01.

If you wont make something like dev environment on local machine use first case (don't forgot open port for other devices), for production - second.